# Strange TCP sequence from a device

Tags: java, tcp

I'm debugging strange connection reset problem in Java and got the next
[Wireshark capture:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRVHY.png)

What can be the cause of repeating that ACK? I'm sure that the device received data correctly as it is executing the command that was sent. But it does not send an answer, only these TCP dup ACK

Comment: that is super strange. having several ACKs without packets looks like either bug in tcp implementation or something in your network is duplicating packets (i think it is packets, because reset is sent, but maybe acks get duplicated too). the RST in the last packets kills the connection due to an error, so there will be no data sent. if you can, capture the traffic on the other side and see what is happening there.

Comment: Hi Effie. Thanks for such informative comment. 
I forgot about this question but it’s already solved. It is how TCP implemented on the device side. Device has a setting for how long to keep connection, during that time it keeps sending that ACK then it sends RST to reset connection. The problem was that some commands can take more than configured time. So we just extended that timeout.